# Blink DIV when new message comes in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page interface using websockets to create a chat much like a live help chat. currently I'm working on the agent end where they can chat with multiple clients at a time. Each of those chats are tabbed (the active chat is shown while the others are hidden).
What I'm trying to do is when a new chat comes in for one of the hidden chats, I want the tab to flash much like you see other Instant Messaging programs to notify you that there's a new message if that chat is not in focus.
How do I do that using jQuery? Examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is it that you've tried thus far?

Comment: @Guest. If you downvote answers without giving a reason, you are disrespecting people who are providing you with free help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With simple `jquery UI.`

Look at  the **pulsate effect**.

http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Comment: is it so hard for @downvoters to post comment? If you think jquery UI is too much, just tell it

Comment: @Guest  yes.we know.you cannot down vote until you got enough reputation.just chill :)

Comment: @Baadshah: Looks like the pulsate is exactly what I need. I'll give it a try. Thanks! (just up voted btw)

Comment: Yes.Thats really looking good for a notification.give a try.Btw i'm not promoting my post :P